# viewの背景がグラデーションせず真っ白になる

Tags: swift, xcode

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //グラデーションの開始色
    let topColor = UIColor(red:147, green:6, blue:229, alpha:1)
    //グラデーションの開始色
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red:23, green:232, blue:252, alpha:1)

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.frame
    gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 20.0

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: view]

Comment: ご質問には「現在はこのコードでこうなってしまう」とともに「自分の望む結果はこんなものだ」と言うのを簡単で良いですから、本文に含めてください。今回はどこが間違っているのかはコードを見れば丸わかりなのですが、何かしらの誤解が入って見当違いの回答が付いてしまうこともあるかもしれません。人間同士がコミュニケーションする場であること、このサイトのQ&A集は資産として蓄積されていくことも考えてご質問を記述してくださると、より多くの人に役立つだろうと思います。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UIColorの書き方を間違えてた。
全然違う箇所だと思ってたわ。

```
//グラデーションの開始色
let topColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 147/255, green: 6/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1.0)
//グラデーションの開始色
let bottomColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 23/255, green: 232/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1.0)
```